# How to increase the counter when a same dictionary key value encountered

Tags: python, dictionary

- I am counting the occurrence of different `DocumentCode` which for now is `BS, F16, SS` which can be different.
- Input

```
ldct_input_body = {
  "ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
  "Input": [
    {
      "DocumentCode": "BS",
      "FileName": "SomethingOne",
      "Object": "base64",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
      "DocumentCode": "BS",
      "FileName": "SomethingTwo",
      "Object": "base64",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
      "DocumentCode": "SS",
      "FileName": "SomethingTwo",
      "Object": "base64",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
      "DocumentCode": "F16",
      "FileName": "SomethingTwo",
      "Object": "base64",
      "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    }
  ]
}
```

- So I am creating a different dictionary by identifying the `DocumentCode` like below

```
ldct_document_code = dict()
ldct_document_code['ObjectEntries'] = []

for lstr_multiple_input_object in ldct_input_body["Input"]:
    ldct_document_code['ObjectEntries'].append(lstr_multiple_input_object['DocumentCode'])
```

- Output

```
{
  "ObjectEntries": [
    "BS",
    "BS",
    "SS",
    "F16"
  ]
}
```

- Now, I am looking to increase the count depending upon how many Inputs of same `DocumentCode` are present
- I had a hard-coded code for it like below

```
for lstr_multiple_input_object in ldct_input_body["Input"]:
    if lstr_multiple_input_object["DocumentCode"] == "BS":
        lint_bank_statement_count += 1
        lint_total_no_of_object += 1
    elif lstr_multiple_input_object["DocumentCode"] == "F16":
        lint_form_16_count += 1
        lint_total_no_of_object += 1
    elif lstr_multiple_input_object["DocumentCode"] == "SS":
        lint_salary_slip_count += 1
        lint_total_no_of_object += 1
```

- But I want it to accept dynamic value of ObjectEntries, get it and then compare it with the Input values.
- Expected Output

```
{
  "ObjectEntries": [
    "BS": 2,
    "SS": 1,
    "F16": 1
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hint - thinking to use *Counter*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this simple code snippet solves your purpose:

```py
ldct_input_body = {
"ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
"Input": [
    {
    "DocumentCode": "BS",
    "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
    "DocumentCode": "BS",
    "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
    "DocumentCode": "SS",
    "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    },
    {
    "DocumentCode": "F16",
    "ObjectFormat": "pdf"
    }
]
}

ldct_document_code = {}
output_dict = {}
for x in ldct_input_body['Input']:
    for k, v in x.items():
        if v == "pdf": continue
        if output_dict.get(v, None) is None:
            output_dict[v] = 1
        else:
            output_dict[v] = output_dict[v] + 1
ldct_document_code['ObjectEntries'] = output_dict

print(ldct_document_code)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'ObjectEntries': {'BS': 2, 'SS': 1, 'F16': 1}}
```